# Put form data into my db with my plugin function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm creating a wp plugin for my website and I have a form on my website who have to put some value into my db. my problem is the data don't want to be put into my db.

I try to change my coding multiple time, and I debug the fonction (the data are recive by the fonction) but actually my code looks like this:

my front page :

```
$date_start = $_POST['startDate'];
$date_end = $_POST['endDate'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$place = $_POST['lieu'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
$user_id = $_POST['id_user'];

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user_id = $current_user->id;

$date_current = date('Y/m/d', time());

frdp_add($user_id, $description, $place, $date_start, $date_end, $value, $date_current, $current_user_id);
```

my plugin page :

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'frais_deplacement';

function frdp_add($user_id, $description, $place, $date_start, $date_end, $value, $date_current, $current_user_id) {
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->insert(
    $table_name,
    array(
        'id_user' => $user_id, 
        'description' => $description,
        'place' => $place,
        'date_start' => $date_start, 
        'date_end' => $date_end, 
        'value' => $value, 
        'created_at' => $date_current, 
        'created_by' => $current_user_id
    ) 
);  
}
```

Comment: add it to accepted arguments `function frdp_add($current_user_id, $description, $place, $date_start, $date_end, $value, $date_current) {`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I can't put the value into my DB because the name of the table wasn't get by the fonction. To do this i have to had `global $table_name;` into my function like this :

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'frais_deplacement';

function frdp_add($user_id, $description, $place, $date_start, $date_end, $value, $date_current, $current_user_id) {
global $wpdb;
global $table_name;

$wpdb->insert(
    $table_name,
    array(
        'id_user' => $user_id, 
        'description' => $description,
        'place' => $place,
        'date_start' => $date_start, 
        'date_end' => $date_end, 
        'value' => $value, 
        'created_at' => $date_current, 
        'created_by' => $current_user_id
    ) 
);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should looks like this, you skipped the arguments in function.

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'frais_deplacement';

function frdp_add($current_user_id, $description, $place, $date_start, $date_end, $value, $date_current, $current_user_id) {
       global $wpdb;

       $wpdb->insert(
$table_name,
array(
    'id_user' => $current_user_id, 
    'description' => $description,
    'place' => $place,
    'date_start' => $date_start, 
    'date_end' => $date_end, 
    'value' => $value, 
    'created_at' => $date_current, 
    'created_by' => $current_user_id,
) 
 );  
}
```

Comment: no need to pass `$current_user_id` twice though - but yeah, this is the answer

Comment: when i do this, I have a fatal error : Redefinition of parameter $current_user_id

Comment: why are you passing 2 times $current_user_id one is enough, if you anyhow pass these 2 then change one parameter name

Comment: @dipmala thanks, I have changed the name of the second var and no fatal error, but nothing goes into my DB

Comment: Here first you need to debug in function check if you are getting the data or not?

Comment: yeah the function get the data and if i put the SQL into my front page, the data goes to my DB